# Field for include HTML5 video player on drupal with popular plateform content

Tags: html, video, drupal, youtube, drupal-7

I'm building a website with drupal and I would like to add a field for adding an html5 video player with content from YouTube and another popular plateform.

I thought that I'd find my happiness with the module "Embedded Media Field". I had to install it and by the same occasion the full "Media" modul.

So I've got a field when I create a new article but when I submit the form I've got the following error message : "Found no valid media with that url."

However when I look at this video : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsAnxoGsCOI", the user can add video easily.
But If you look the video at the minute 3, when the user create the field, He can choose between different fields types like "Embedded Video", "Embedded Audio" and over.
I don't have this possibility !

Seem the module "Embedded Media Field" should be included in "Embedded Media Field," but I have a big doubt because it don't appear in my list of modules ... and I don't find it in the module directory on https://www.drupal.org/project/

So who can say me what module to use for :
- adding an html5 responsive player;
- adding a video gallery;

Big thankz by advance !

Mickael

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [video module](https://www.drupal.org/project/video). This module will take care of the video field, conversion, thumbnails, etc. Then you will need to add a HTML5 video player module to display the video. I've used VideoJS and it's worked pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not what I want, I want to import a video from a plateform like you tube or vimeo.

Answer (score 0):

An easy method to put video up - as long as you have the files - is to use my newly released HTML5 SimplePlayer https://www.drupal.org/project/simpleplayer

It works with audio and video - but it has NO Flash fallback, so really old browsers won't work. The thing is: there are very few of those now. Basically ALL mobile devices work, and any computer you've gotten in the last decade can run this.

It's low-weight for mobile, and it has no other required dependencies.